# Trapezoidal method using fixed point iteration

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fixed-point-theorems, differential, implicit-function

I am not sure how to apply the trapezoidal method using fixed point iteration, at each step, to this equation $\frac{dy}{dt}=\cos{(\frac{2y}{4})}$.

Any help will be appreciated as I've been stuck on this for the past few days.

Comment: Is the formula correct? Why not write just $\cos(\frac{y}{2})$?

Comment: sorry, it was meant to be 3 instead of 2.

Answer (score 0):

The implicit trapezoidal method for $y'=f(y)$ reads as
$$
\frac{y_{n+1}-y_n}{h}=\frac{f(y_{n+1})+f(y_n)}2.
$$
The usual fixed-point equation formulation of that is
$$
y_{n+1}=y_n+\frac{h}2(f(y_{n+1})+f(y_n))=r_n+\frac{h}2f(y_{n+1})
$$
That is, you compute $r_n=y_n+\frac{h}2f(y_n)$, an then iterate
$$
z^1=y_n+hf(y_n),~~~ z^{j+1}=r_n+\frac{h}2f(z^j),
$$
and set $y_{n+1}=z^j$ after the changes in the iteration become small enough.

This converges if $Lh<2$ where $L$ is a Lipschitz constant of $f$.

Comment: Could you apply it to the question, so that I can see how it works. For some reason i am still a little confused?

Comment: You just insert $f(y)=\cos(\frac34y)$. There is nothing more to it, no simplifications.

Comment: I've plugged it in, and started solving for h=0.1, but the results don't quite match the Euler's method, so i'm not too sure if its correct or not

Comment: Do not use an inferior method to compare against, use a higher order method or compare to a run with half the step-size to get an error estimate via Richardson extrapolation.

Comment: I think I've confused myself more now. my y(0)=0 and started from there, so my z^0 is 0 and  z^1 is 0.05. Would that be correct?

Comment: With $h=0.1$ you should get $r_0=0.05$, $z^1=0.1$, and $z^2\approx 0.09975$, due to $\cos(0)=1$, $\cos(h)\approx 1-\frac12h^2$.